# Spring Boot security JWT hasAuthority not work properly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, auth0

I secure our Spring Boot API with Auth0 and JWT.

When I decode JWT the result is:

```json
{
  "iss": "https://****.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "auth0|62483c747a2519006fd75914",
  "aud": [
    "https://***.com/",
    "https://***.com/userinfo"
  ],
  "iat": 1648903665,
  "exp": 1648990065,
  "azp": "ufoZPRxuRqAeulM5u7R5RdlddXvPnOTn",
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "permissions": [
    "read:brands"
  ]
}
```

In the permission array there is `read:brands`. But when I try to limit API it's not working and returns 403 status for GET `/admin/v1/brands`.

Here is security config:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${auth0.audience}")
    private String audience;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuer;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/v2/api-docs",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui/**",
                "/webjars/**",
                "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html"
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/admin/v1/brands").hasAuthority("read:brands")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .decoder(jwtDecoder());
    }

    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new AudienceValidator(audience);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> validator = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withAudience, withIssuer);

        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder) JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);
        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(validator);
        return jwtDecoder;
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        var config =  new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        config.setAllowedMethods(List.of(
                HttpMethod.GET.name(),
                HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
                HttpMethod.POST.name(),
                HttpMethod.DELETE.name()
        ));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found it!

I had to add `jwtAuthenticationConverter`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    public static final String AUTHORITIES_CLAIM_NAME = "permissions";

    @Value("${auth0.audience}")
    private String audience;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuer;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/v2/api-docs",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui/**",
                "/webjars/**",
                "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html"
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html"
                )
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/admin/v1/brands")
                .hasAuthority("read:brands")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter())
                .decoder(jwtDecoder());
    }

    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new AudienceValidator(audience);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> validator = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withAudience, withIssuer);

        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder) JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);
        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(validator);
        return jwtDecoder;
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        var config =  new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        config.setAllowedMethods(List.of(
                HttpMethod.GET.name(),
                HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
                HttpMethod.POST.name(),
                HttpMethod.DELETE.name()
        ));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }

    protected JwtAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter() {
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        authoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("");
        authoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName(AUTHORITIES_CLAIM_NAME);

        JwtAuthenticationConverter converter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        converter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(authoritiesConverter);
        return converter;
    }
}
```